# Remix (static analysis) gives a warning on protected selfdestruct

Tags: remix, selfdestruct, warnings

I have the following SC containing the protected selfdestruct:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;
contract Discontinue {
   address payable owner ;
   constructor () public {
      owner = msg . sender ;
   }
   function Terminate (address payable addr) public {
      if ( msg.sender == owner ){
         selfdestruct ( addr );
      }
   }
}
```

I think Remix should not warn on protected selfdestruct because selfdestruct is helpful to get rid of a useless and buggy SC. I have attached the image.[image: remix(static analysis) warning on protected selfdestruct]

Zulfi.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code has so many typos. In the constructor, there should be `==`  not a single one and then its `msg.sender` not `msg . sender`.
Your code should look like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.7.1;
contract Discontinue {
   address payable owner ;

   constructor () {
      owner == msg.sender ;
   }

   function Terminate (address payable addr) public {
      if ( msg.sender == owner ){
         selfdestruct (addr);
      }
   }
}
```

Now, this compiled successfully for me. Another thing is,
You are using a very old compiler which is full of bugs in Remix.
I prefer the `^0.7.x` version. Or If you want only `^0.5.1`
I would advise you to code on VS Code, Maybe you will not get these errors there.

Hope this will help you :)

(Edit)
Actually, if I try to compile this code with `0.5.1` It tells me to put contructors' visibility, when I put `public` with the constructor, it gives me another error saying, `public` should not be there.
And one thing more if I comment out the constructor and add the owner hardcoded like this `address payable owner = msg.sender ;` it compiles successfully.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;
contract Discontinue {
   address payable owner = msg.sender ;

   // constructor public () {
   //    owner == msg.sender ;
   // }

   function Terminate (address payable addr) public {
      if ( msg.sender == owner ){
         selfdestruct (addr);
      }
   }
}
```

This compiled successfully.

Comment: That worked bro or not? Lemme know pls :)

Comment: Welcome. Sorry why are you initializing outside the constructor, what's the purpose of a constructor?

Comment: As I said, If I compile the code with the constructor with ^0.7.x compiler. It complies successfully but, if I try to compile this code with 0.5.1 It tells me to put contructors' visibility, when I put public with the constructor, it gives me another error saying, public should not be there. And one thing more if I comment out the constructor and add the owner hardcoded like this address payable `owner = msg.sender ;` it compiles successfully.

Comment: So basically If you want the constructor you have to use ^0.7.x solidity but if you want to go with the ^0.5.x solidity, then for me it's creating some more errors. Try the above code with a different compiler yourself. AND also, I think your problem (which you initially posted) is solved. selfdestruct was giving you error because your code had some typos. I fixed it, and now selfdestruct is working. So you shouldmark this answer as correct, and if you are facing another issue then please open a new issue. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, my question was not about compilation.